# Keep the selection while scrolling in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have a lot of data and I need to create a button, or when I click, I take all the selected lines.

However, when scrolling down, the lines selected at the top are deselected due to the virtual DOM, which is problematic.

Is there a way to save the selected lines while scrolling?

thank you

Comment: Hi, can you edit your message and show us some code with what you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can provide an example of what you are currently doing, I can look at it.  However, it seems to work correctly for me.

I am using `getSelectedData`, to get the data, but if you want the row component instead, use `getSelectedRows`.

Here is an example with 10000 rows.
https://jsfiddle.net/70odrgpj/

Create the table.  Select the rows.  Call `table.getSelectedData()` to get the selected rows.  This returns the rows, even if they are not currently rendered in the HTML

(In this case table is the Tabulator object.  If you don't have the reference, you can use `Tabulator.prototype.findTable('table-selector')` to get a list of Tabulator's matching the `'table-selector'`.)

Comment: As an example, I don't have a specific one. Sorry. 

I understand better, I was using "getSelectedRows" for retrieval, I didn't know "getSelectedData", which doesn't work the same way. On the other hand I notice on your example that the lines remain selected during a scroll, instead of disappearing.

Maybe this part is related to the fact that I'm using an older version of tabulator? (4.4.3) If it's related to that, I'll manage to fix the problem, having made a lot of changes on this library for the needs of the site.

Thanks you

Comment: Sorry, I used the data function instead of the row function. I believe either can be used without issue. I’ll update the answer to mention that.